# Очередь задач. Выполнение по расписанию. На чем реализовать?

Tags: php, activemq, rabbitmq, mysql

Будет примерно такое:
Пользователи сервиса будут настраивать параметры расписания публикации сообщений:

1. Публиковать одну запись в заданное время
2. Публиковать записи каждые хх минут

Далее выбирает дни недели, время и период публикации или точное время
После этого система по расписанию публикует что то.
Проблема еще в том что расписание будут редактировать часто.

Вопрос в том, как это все организовать, с помощью чего(ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ, Gearman)?
С таким никогда не сталкивался, и хочется не ошибиться с выбором.

Предполагается, что пользователей будет много(1000+), каждый может настраивать десятки расписаний. 
Возможно будет необходимость использовать несколько серверов для распределения нагрузки.

Серверная часть будет на php + mysql

Comment: Расписание которое устанавливается пользователем будет храниться в отдельной таблице в той же БД

Answer (score 1):

Gearman получше будет.

Вк апи юзаешь?

Comment: Чем тут Gearman пригодится? Публикация новости задача «лёгкая», быстрая. +/- несколько миллисекунд от указанного времени публикации не критичны, чтобы разносить задачу на парк серверов )

Comment: может и не несколько миллисекунд, загрузка изображений, несколько соц сетей и тд

Comment: Ну вообще-то все можно на одном сервере организовать

Comment: Можешь тогда использовать  rabbitMQ, на хабре есть принцип его работы

Answer (score 1):

`Процесс 1 => Буфер => Процесс 2`

Процесс 1 отвечает за «таймер» и наполняет Буфер на обработку. Второй процесс занимается тем что берёт очередную задачу из буфера и тут же ее исполняет (публикует новость).

Я бы просто держал задачи в БД: `{timestamp, user_id, публикации_json}` 
Раз в X секунд смотрел, какие публикации на подходе (в области +/- Y секунд), и вынимал их из базы в буфер на обработку.

Буфер можно реализовать и как ещё одну таблицу в БД, и в Redis держать. Артиллерия вроде кролика и gearman'а, по-моему, перебор.

Процесс 2 берёт очередную новость к публикации из Буфера и публикует её. «Следующий!»

По мере роста этого сервиса автопостинга, и до попадания его в неизбежный глубокий бан, можно будет добавлять сервера для Процесса2, при условии, что читают из Буфера они эксклюзивно. Напр. [LPOP](http://redis.io/commands/lpop) в Redis (при прочтении элемент вынимается из списка).

Comment: почему вы думаете, что сервис попадет в бан? В техподдержке vk дали понять, что не против этого, если не переусердствовать. 
Вот я думал о такой реализации


Есть таблица с этим расписанием на MySQL
Cron каждую минуту или несколько секунд заглядывает в таблицу и создает задачи на ближайшее выполнение в очередь(но какая технология больше подойдет), у которых подошло время.

Так как публикация может занимать больше минуты - 
загрузка изображений, публикация в несколько соцсетей и тд.

Comment: [Насчёт бана например](https://vk.com/smmpub?w=wall-43503600_81212). Там, видимо, брали контент автоматически с других ресурсов.

С сервера на быстром канале картинки грузятся быстро. «Больше минуты» — это если грузить видео, наверное.

Работа с API соц. через cURL позволяет [многопоточность](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-multi-exec.php) — можно напр. сразу грузить 100 картинок параллельно из одного php скрипта.

При большом количестве пользователей станут всерьёз заметны пики нагрузки: напр. ровно в час будет много больше публикаций, чем на час +2 минуты.

Comment: с баном это все решаемо, и банят группы сейчас за некачественный контент. а не приложения.

если будет много пользователей и нагрузки, будет несколько серверов, для этого тут и требуется маштабируемый менеджер задач. Может чего то я еще не понимаю)